# Fab button on tabview when clicked not replacing another Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have tab view on `Fragment` itself. On first tab I have `FAB` button. When `FAB` `button` is clicked it is not replacing the tab view layout with new `Fragment` layout. New `Fragment` layout get overlapped on tab view Layout.

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: problem is with your container on which you are committing fragment transaction.

Answer (score 0):

use replace instead of add here is example

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
transaction.replace(R.id.totalpropcontainer, contactUs);//Replace by your fragment
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to initialized fab button static and if you have five tabs and open in first tab click set fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); and others tab click fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);

or On fab, button click you write this code:

```
   FragmentTransaction ft =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new yourFragment());
            ft.commit();
```